# Array is not setting data in sequence

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to store all check box value to database with related menuid but my array is not storing data as according to menuid. i have attached all code which i am using if any body can help me it would be appreciating thanks in advance.

> View File

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading bg-white">
            <strong>Users Groups</strong><br>
            <small class="text-muted">Create User Groups</small>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">User Group Title*</label>
                    <input value="" type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="shop_name" placeholder="Ex: xyz shop">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="example" class="table table-hover b-t b-b">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Item</th>
                                <th>Add</th>
                                <th>Edit</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                            $n = 1;
                            foreach ( $list_users as $row) { ?>
                                <tr>

                                    <?php if ($row['IsChild'] != null and  $row['IsChild'] != 1) { ?>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['alias']; ?></td>

                                        <td>
                                            <input  value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" type="text" name="menu_id[]">
                                            <input checked style="opacity:0;" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>--0--a" id="add1<?php echo $n;?>" type="checkbox" name="add[]">
                                            <input value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>--1--a" id="add<?php echo $n;?>" type="checkbox" name="add[]">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input checked style="opacity:0;" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>--0--e" id="edit1<?php echo $n;?>" type="checkbox" name="edit[]">
                                            <input value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>--1--e" id="edit<?php echo $n;?>" type="checkbox" name="edit[]">
                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            <input checked style="opacity:0;" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>--0--d" id="delete1<?php echo $n;?>" type="checkbox" name="delete[]">
                                            <input value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>--1--d" id="delete<?php echo $n;?>" type="checkbox" name="delete[]">
                                        </td>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </tr>
                            <?php $n++; }   ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading bg-dark">
           <strong>Publish</strong><br>
            <small class="text-muted">Click to publish</small>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p><strong>Status: </strong> </p>
            <p><strong>Date Created: </strong></p>
            <p><strong>Date Updated: </strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel bg-light" style="margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 10px; text-align: right;" >
            <input value="Update Now" style="padding: 7px 20px; border: 0px; border-radius: 10px;" type="submit" class=" btn-success">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Controller function

```
function save_user_groups()
    {

        //For generating user_group_master_id manually
        $this->load->model('settings/model_users');
        $banner_id_main = $this->model_users->get_user_master_id();
        foreach ($banner_id_main as $row)
        {
            $user_group_m_id = $row['user_group_master_id'];
        }

        $title   = $this->input->post('title');
        $menu_id = $this->input->post('menu_id');
        $add     = $this->input->post('add');
        $edit    = $this->input->post('edit');
        $delete  = $this->input->post('delete');

        $count = count($menu_id);

        //array for insert main banner detail in database
        $user_group_master = array(
            'user_group_master_id' => $user_group_m_id,
            'user_group_title' => $title
        );

        $g_rights=array();

        for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
        {
            $g_rights[] = array(
                'user_group_master_id' => $user_group_m_id,
                'MenuID' => $menu_id[$i],
                'chkadd'=>$add[$i],
                'chkedit'=>$edit[$i],
                'chkdel' => $delete[$i]
            );
        }



        print_r($user_group_master);
        print_r($g_rights);
        exit();

        $data['rights'] = $g_rights ;

        $this->load->model('settings/model_users');

        if ($create = $this->model_users->save_user_group($user_group_master, $g_rights))
        {
            $data['product_created'] = 'thank you';
            $this->load->view('setting/users' , $data);
        }
    }
```

> Result of Array
>   **menu id is not populating in right way in chkadd, chkedit,chkdelete, please help**

```
Array
(
    [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
    [user_group_title] =&gt; 
)
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 51
            [chkadd] =&gt; 51--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 51--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 51--0--d
        )

    [1] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 10
            [chkadd] =&gt; 51--1--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 51--1--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 10--0--d
        )

    [2] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 11
            [chkadd] =&gt; 10--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 10--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 11--0--d
        )

    [3] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 12
            [chkadd] =&gt; 11--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 10--1--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 12--0--d
        )

    [4] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 14
            [chkadd] =&gt; 12--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 11--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 14--0--d
        )

    [5] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 15
            [chkadd] =&gt; 14--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 11--1--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 15--0--d
        )

    [6] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 16
            [chkadd] =&gt; 15--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 12--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 16--0--d
        )

    [7] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 17
            [chkadd] =&gt; 16--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 14--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 17--0--d
        )

    [8] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 18
            [chkadd] =&gt; 17--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 15--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 18--0--d
        )

    [9] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 19
            [chkadd] =&gt; 18--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 16--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 19--0--d
        )

    [10] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 20
            [chkadd] =&gt; 19--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 17--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 20--0--d
        )

    [11] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 21
            [chkadd] =&gt; 20--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 18--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 21--0--d
        )

    [12] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 22
            [chkadd] =&gt; 21--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 19--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 22--0--d
        )

    [13] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 29
            [chkadd] =&gt; 22--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 20--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 29--0--d
        )

    [14] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 30
            [chkadd] =&gt; 29--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 21--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 30--0--d
        )

    [15] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 31
            [chkadd] =&gt; 30--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 22--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 31--0--d
        )

    [16] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 32
            [chkadd] =&gt; 31--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 29--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 32--0--d
        )

    [17] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 33
            [chkadd] =&gt; 32--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 30--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 33--0--d
        )

    [18] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 35
            [chkadd] =&gt; 33--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 31--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 35--0--d
        )

    [19] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 36
            [chkadd] =&gt; 35--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 32--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 36--0--d
        )

    [20] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 37
            [chkadd] =&gt; 36--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 33--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 37--0--d
        )

    [21] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 38
            [chkadd] =&gt; 37--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 35--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 38--0--d
        )

    [22] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 39
            [chkadd] =&gt; 38--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 36--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 39--0--d
        )

    [23] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 40
            [chkadd] =&gt; 39--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 37--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 40--0--d
        )

    [24] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 41
            [chkadd] =&gt; 40--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 38--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 41--0--d
        )

    [25] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 43
            [chkadd] =&gt; 41--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 39--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 43--0--d
        )

    [26] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 44
            [chkadd] =&gt; 43--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 40--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 44--0--d
        )

    [27] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 45
            [chkadd] =&gt; 44--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 41--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 45--0--d
        )

    [28] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 46
            [chkadd] =&gt; 45--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 43--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 46--0--d
        )

    [29] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 47
            [chkadd] =&gt; 46--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 44--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 47--0--d
        )

    [30] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 48
            [chkadd] =&gt; 47--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 45--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 48--0--d
        )

    [31] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 49
            [chkadd] =&gt; 48--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 46--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 49--0--d
        )

    [32] =&gt; Array
        (
            [user_group_master_id] =&gt; 1
            [MenuID] =&gt; 50
            [chkadd] =&gt; 49--0--a
            [chkedit] =&gt; 47--0--e
            [chkdel] =&gt; 50--0--d
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that when posting form data, checkboxes that are not checked do not show up in the post array. Knowing that, if some of your checkboxes are not checked, you can't simply try to find out if there were checked/unchecked using the numeric index of the add, edit, and delete arrays. Consider the following test:

```
<?php

// You have three menu IDs
$menu_id = array(
    '1','2','3'
);

// Only one checkbox was checked for "add"
$add = array(
    '1--0--a'
);

// Only two checkboxes were checked for "edit"
$edit = array(
    '1--0--e',
    '2--0--e'
);

// All three checkboxes were checked for "delete"
$delete = array(
    '1--0--d',
    '2--0--d',
    '3--0--d'
);

// Loop through the menu IDs, because they will always be posted
foreach( $menu_id as $id )
{
    $temp = array('MenuId' => $id);

    // Check if this menu ID has a checkbox checked for add
    foreach( $add as $a )
    {
        $parts = explode( '--', $a );
        if( $parts[0] == $id )
        {
            $temp['chkadd'] = $a;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Check if this menu ID has a checkbox checked for edit
    foreach( $edit as $e )
    {
        $parts = explode( '--', $e );
        if( $parts[0] == $id )
        {
            $temp['chkedit'] = $e;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Check if this menu ID has a checkbox checked for delete
    foreach( $delete as $d )
    {
        $parts = explode( '--', $d );
        if( $parts[0] == $id )
        {
            $temp['chkdel'] = $d;
            break;
        }
    }

    $final[] = $temp;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $final );
echo '</pre>';
```

This test should enlighten you as to how missing checkbox data would not longer be a problem. Now you can fix your code.